# Why does my geocoding function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Im geocoding my address, from something like "Address 150, City" to it's latitude and longitude using Google Geocoding API. At the end of a function, im trying to return an object, which contains these two as shown in code below.

I've thought that the problem may be, that the coding takes quite some time, and since I wanted to resolve this problem today and I haven't learned await and async with promises and stuff(i will do that tommorow, dont worry), I used setTimeout instead, but it didnt solve the problem even thought I was calling console.log after the coding was done. Since I'm new to JS, I then just tried to wrap it into variable, just play with the code a little, but neither did help.

```
            // address
            var address = "Address 156, City"
            function geocode(address) {
                axios.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", {
                    params: {
                        address: address,
                        key: "AIzaSyDaXOpbCeLYeRxWXtuSQQEbQzR14PejczM"
                    }
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        let lngLat = {
                            lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                            lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng}
                        console.log(lngLat) // here it shows me my object
                        return lngLat;
                    })
            }
            let geocodedAddress = geocode(address);
            setTimeout(function () { console.log(geocodedAddress); }, 3000);               
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just do the actual work where you're calling ` return lngLat;` - promises don't return values like that.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Sometimes I tend to overcomplicate. Thanks for solving my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You have no `return` in your function. The `return` in `then()` does not return to the outer function.

In addition, the request is asynchronous so you need to return the `axios.get` promise and use another `then()` to access the data when function is called

```
function geocode(address) {
  // return the promise
  return axios.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", {
      params: {
        address: address,
        key: "AIzaSyDaXOpbCeLYeRxWXtuSQQEbQzR14PejczM"
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      let lngLat = {
        lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
        lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
      };     
      return lngLat;
    });
}

// usage
geocode(address).then(lngLat => {
  console.log(lngLat);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have access to your entire code, but an async/await approach to solve your issue you would be:

```
// address
var address = "Address 156, City"
async function geocode(address) {
  const response = await axios.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", {
    params: {
      address: address,
      key: "AIzaSyDaXOpbCeLYeRxWXtuSQQEbQzR14PejczM"
    }
  })

  let lngLat = {
    lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
    lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
  }
  console.log(lngLat) // here it shows me my object
  return lngLat; 
}

let geocodedAddress = await geocode(address);
console.log(geocodedAddress);               
}
});
```

Note how async/await allows you to write simple sequential logic to perform asynchronous operations.

Comment: Need another async function to do `let geocodedAddress = await geocode(address);`

Comment: That is true, but I'm assuming there's no reason the other function cannot be `async` as well.